# webclient upload values async over ssl c# xamarin

Tags: c#, android, ssl, xamarin, webclient

I was wondering how to use WebClient.UploadValuesAsync over ssl? I guess it implicitly doesn't use ssl.

and another one, is it good practice to use WebClient in android apps?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using System.Net.HttpClient instead as there are HttpClientHandlers that are made for each platform which Xamarin provides.

Simply providing a HTTPS resource would yield calls against your endpoint which uses SSL. No magic here, or anything extra needed to get that to work.

Comment: Could you provide simple example? I mean the simplest code I can start with since I have never worked with httpclient, thanks